# Rails 5: Access create method from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing a client dashboard, there the client is able to see new offers, reservations and more.

The problem now is that I have a `reservations controller` and a `dashboards controller`

I want to display a pay button in my `index.html.erb` from the `dashboards` folder. For example:

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>

<%= form_for([@service, @service.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
  <%= f.submit "Bestellen", class: "btn btn-primary", style: 'float:right' %>
</div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

But then I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `reservations' for nil:NilClass):
```

This is my reservations controller:

```
  def create
    service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

if current_user == service.user
  flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht dein eigenes Angebot kaufen"
elsif current_user.stripe_id.blank?
  flash[:alert] = "Füge eine Zahlungsmehtode hinzu"
  return redirect_to payment_method_path
else
  @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
  @reservation.service = service
  @reservation.price = service.price

  charge(service, @reservation)
end
redirect_to dashboard_path
  end
```

My dashboards controller

```
  def index
    @services = Service.all
  end
```

So I thought I would just create a file `_form.html.erb` in my reservations folder and then use `<%= render 'reservations/form %>` in my dashboards `index`, but this didn't work.

Comment: If you read the error, it's telling you that `@service` is nil. If you set that to something appropriate (maybe `Service.new` or similar) in the controller then you'll have a better chance of it working.

Comment: Isnt it telling me that reservatios is nil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the loop variable instead of the undefined instance variable...

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <%= form_for [service, service.reservations.new] do |f| %>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
       <%= f.submit "Bestellen", class: "btn btn-primary", style: 'float:right' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I try this, I get undefined local variable or method for `service`

Comment: Well, the button must be inside my loop, I'll add the whole view.

Comment: This worked, but somehow I thought that I already tried this. Anyways, thank you.